# How to speed up zoom-in/zoom-out of the image with swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

How to reduce the overhead of the image zoom in and zoom out.

Here is my code which takes too long time to zoom-in/zoom-out the image...

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    int myX = 0;
    int myY = 0;

    if (e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {
        try {
            float amount = e.getWheelRotation() * 5f;
            myX = (int) (label.getWidth() + amount);
            myY = (int) (label.getHeight() + amount);
            imgX = myX;
            imgY = myY;
            label.setSize(myX, myY);
            scalledItemImage = itemImage.getScaledInstance(imgX, imgY,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scalledItemImage);
            label.setIcon(icon);
            repaint();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to speedup the image rendering with the expected resolution and clarity of the image.

Comment: maybe you simply call scalledItemImage = itemImage.getScaledInstance(imgX, imgY, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);

Comment: Beware that the size of the label might not represent the size of the image...

Comment: Take a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: wow, thanks mad programmer, thats a very interesting article!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call the scale method in a wrong way....

- BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB = 6; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR
- Image.SCALE_FAST = 2; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.Image.SCALE_FAST

try to call :

```
scalledItemImage = itemImage.getScaledInstance(imgX, imgY,
                BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
```

(as proposed above)

Comment: you can accept the answer by pressing the checkbox next to my solution ^^

Comment: ahaahahaaa =) thank Andrew, but i think that's in vain!

Comment: +1 for fast reply @MartinFrank . if my question is legal then you can rate it up and select it as a favorite..thanks in advance

Comment: it was a 'legal' question, so ok +1 ^^